# Add new user in next cloud from Android client

Tags: android, api, addition, owncloud, nextcloud

I am working on next cloud server. I am creating folder on server from client end (Android) and uploading/downloading files successfully. I need to add a new user into the next cloud server. I am using guide from
[Next Cloud User Provisioning API](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_provisioning_api.html).

Here I want to hit the server, please tell me what to write in header and content type section. I am getting response code=200, but when I open the returned url, it gives "invalide query". Any help?

Answer (score 1):

there's an omission on some of those API docs - there's this `'OCS-APIREQUEST'` header that needs to be set to `true` for some requests to succeed; in your case:

```
curl -X POST https://<your-owncloud>/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users?format=json \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'OCS-APIREQUEST: true' \
  -d 'userid=<username>&password=<password>'
```

Will return:

```
{
    "ocs": {
        "meta": {
            "status": "ok",
            "statuscode": 100,
            "message": null
        },
        "data": []
    }
}
```

The `"statuscode": 100` indicates that the user has been created. Does this also work out for you?

For more info on the (*non-standard*) status codes of this request, check: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration/user/user_provisioning_api.html#users-adduser

Comment: I want to create user from Android side. Is there any possibility that I can create user (not add) from client side?

Comment: @MominKhan hm, I fear not from the client, no. The client is meant to be an user-facing interface. Admin tasks are relegated to the webUI. You can however, create a custom client build for your needs if you have Android experience - https://github.com/owncloud/android. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Alfageme - I now understand that only admin has the privilege  to create new user but that too from WebUI (as you said)  not from client side (yet). From client side (in my case, it is android), one can only create new folders using admin name and admin password. And yes I am using the same app which you shared in the comment.